# Unity check if scene == gamescene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, scene

I'm a bit new to Unity, so im asking for you guys help.

How can i check if the Scene == "gamescene"?

I tried something like this:

```
if(SceneManager.loadedScene == "gamescene") { do something }
```

I want to do an auto save only if the opened scene is the "gamescene".

But i haven't seen it working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is right, but you should use [SceneManager.GetActiveScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html)().name.

Answer (score 2):

Your need to use `SceneManager.GetActiveScene()` then get the name of the scene from it.

```
if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "gamescene") {  }
```